# What is the best layer to handle a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, dao

My system has these classes:

```
PersonBean - handles the requests from the view;
PersonService - provides all operations for the PersonBeam;
PersonDao - provides data access from db to Service classes;
```

I have a `findById(int personId)` method on my `PersonDao` class. When `PersonDao` cannot find any `Person` with the provided `Id` it returns `Null`. Where should I handle the `Null`? In which layer?

Comment: I would handle NPEs from Data layer (i.e. entities) and upwards (access layer, service layer, etc.). You've got to remember that NPEs can be thrown at different layers as mentioned below by @mnd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the null should be passed back as far as possible in the stack, so that it can be handled at each layer differently if needed (and depending on the path to the `PersonDao`, if it differs in other areas of the code). In this case I think it would make sense to handle the `null` in `PersonBean`.

This is all assuming that you're only talking about a `null` reference, not a `NullPointerException`, if that was the case, handle it at the lowest level, which would be the `PersonDao`.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a "correct" answer to this. However, maybe I can provide some advice.

Do not catch it at the repository level, as returning `null` is common practice for when something doesn't exist. As far as where to handle it, it shouldn't surface to the user and you also don't want to have to worry about whether it might be null at multiple areas in the application.

So, pick the lowest layer in which you can handle it appropriately (because you have enough information about why you're requesting it) so you don't have to deal with it everywhere. An alternative, would be to define service methods like:

`getIfExists(String id)` that may return null, and `get(String id)` that will throw an exception if null (if you are ever querying where you KNOW that the id should correspond to a user and something is wrong if it does not).

Answer (score 1):

You need to think whether not finding a person is an exceptional case. Is it something that occurs *outside normal program-flow*? If so, I would throw semantically-valid exception that implies that the record was not found.

Hibernate (for example) has two retrieval-methods: `get` and `load`. `load` will throw an exception when a record cannot be found, whereas `get` returns `null`. So you could use a similar approach. This makes it implicit in the contract that one method expects a record to be found, whereas the other does not.

As far as where to handle it, if you are returning `null`, then I would handle it at the farthest layer back, i.e., at the layer where you are actually asking for an instance of a `Person`. It is only at that layer where you can make an informative decision as to what to do with a `null` `Person` instance.

If you think not finding a record is an exceptional case, then I would throw an exception (as I mentioned before, not `NullPointerException`, but some other exception that implies that the record was not found) when the record is not found.